# Custom event landing page error

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

we are using GTM + UA for tracking. In some cases such as a new register, new publish etc. we are firing custom events using the *dataLayer*

```
  dataLayer.push({
    'event': 'gaTriggerEvent',
    'gaEventCategory': "goals",
    'gaEventAction': "register",
    'gaEventLabel': "facebook"
  });
```

Everything is setup correctly and we can see all the events being tracked by GA. 
The problem we have is that the *landing page* in GA for the event we fire when user registers using Facebook Omniauth is reporting wrong Landing page.

For example, user enters URL **"/"**, goes to **"/xxxx"**, hits *Register with Facebook*, facebook calls for our callback URL which redirects the user to **"/user/welcome"** page. When we see second dimension *Landing Page* for this event it reports the **"/user/welcome"** and not the **"/"** - the entrance

We checked the event details with GA debugger and the *clientId* stays the same in all pages so there is no explanation why GA loses track of where the user who fired the event entered the site.

Also, is there any way to debug GA in real time like in Mixpanel? It's quite frustrating not knowing what the reported landing page for a event is until the next day :\

Thanks

Comment: Even with the same client id a new session starts when the source/medium information changes, so you might want to check if this happens during your FB redirect. As for debugging tools , Google offers (as Chrome extensions) the Google Analytics Debugger and the Tag Assistant, a third party extension with similar functions is Omnibug, you can use a proxy like Fiddler, or simply built-in tools like the browsers network tab and GAs realtime view.

Comment: Hi Eike, "Even with the same client id a new session starts when the source/medium information changes" - I will check it, but I doubt that this is the case. Then again logic behind LANDING PAGE might be as simple as you say - every visit coming from another domain (even if the user has the valid session) is counted as a new entrance...

Comment: Every visit from another domain counts as a new visit. That'S straight from the documentation (even though the docs say "campaign information" referrals etc are explictly includeded, that's why there is a referral exclusion list. "Every time a user's campaign source changes, Google Analytics opens a new session. Generally speaking, the campaign updates anytime the user arrives at your site via a search engine, referring website, or campaign tagged URL."  - from here: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2731565?hl=en

Comment: Thanks for the clarification :) So, the session is not only controlled by the time passed between the 2 visits... Interesting. Now it makes sense :D. Can you convert your comment into a response and I'll accept it ;) Cheers

Comment: You were right: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2731565?hl=en